# Windows Phone: How can I get a list of supported resolutions for the camera C++/CX?

Tags: encoding, camera, record, resolution, c++-cx

I have the following function to initialize the camera:

```
LmiBool LmiVideoCapturerWinRTImplementation::Initialize(){
m_bRecording = LMI_FALSE;
m_bSuspended = LMI_TRUE;
m_bPreviewing = LMI_FALSE;
m_pMediaCapture = ref new MediaCapture();
try{
    auto task = create_task(m_pMediaCapture->InitializeAsync(m_settings));
    if (task.wait() == completed){
        m_pMediaCapture->Failed += ref new MediaCaptureFailedEventHandler(this, &LmiVideoCapturerWinRTImplementation::MediaCaptureFailed);
        m_pMediaCapture->RecordLimitationExceeded += ref new Windows::Media::Capture::RecordLimitationExceededEventHandler(this, &LmiVideoCapturerWinRTImplementation::RecordLimitationExceeded);
        // create a video encoding profile with the default settings (Auto uses the current camera settings)
        m_EncodingProfile = MediaEncodingProfile::CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality::HD720p);
        m_pMediaCaptureSettings = m_pMediaCapture->MediaCaptureSettings;
        return LMI_TRUE;
    }
    else{
        return LMI_FALSE;
    }
}
catch (Exception ^ex){
    return LMI_FALSE;
}
}
```

Now as you can see, I am creating the video file using the following resolution: HD720p. 
I found that the enum VideoEncodingQuality contains a list of resolutions the encoder could use.
What I want to know is, if it is possible to get a list of the resolutions that the device supports, somehow, so that if I choose HD1080p and my phone doesn't support that, it will not crash.
Is is possible in C++/CX to get a list of supported resolutions back from my device?